# Chrome mobile remote debugging with portforwarding: Android phone cannot connect to localhost

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, remote-debugging

I'm following [these instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#port-forwarding) to enable Chrome mobile remote debugging with port forwarding, connecting my Sony Experia Z30 via USB to my macbook.

From my macbook I can see the device, and I can screencast tabs from the mobile chrome browser. However, port forwarding is not working:

- I have set port 3000 to forward to localhost:3000, where I have a rails server running on my local machine.
- From `chrome://inspect/#devices` I can see the Device name with the green light next to `:3000`. However, when I type `localhost:3000`
- When I type `localhost:3000` into my mobile browser I get errors

If I'm connected to mobile data

`ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved`, on a page generated by the mobile provider

If I turn mobile data off

```
Unable to connect to the proxy server
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED`
```

So clearly the phone is not using the USB connection to my local machine the way it should be.